# Dynamic JointJS element size

Tags: javascript, jointjs

Other than creating your own custom HTML elements, is there a way to have the size of the elements (say, a rectangle) be dependent on what you store in it. For instance if I want to display `Foo` then the element is small, but for `This is a really long string` the element will be much larger. Is this possible without creating custom elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it with a custom element model.

If below is your Element model, (Notice it has fixed width and height)

```
joint.shapes.custom.CustomElement = joint.shapes.devs.Model.extend({
defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
    type: 'custom.CustomElement',
    position: { x: 300, y: 50 },
    size: { width: 90, height: 90 },
}, joint.shapes.devs.Model.prototype.defaults) });
```

And assuming that you are setting the label of the element when instantiate time, you can follow below approach,

```
var label = "My Element Label";
var elem = new joint.shapes.custom.CustomElement({
    size: { width: label.length*12, height: 80 },
    attrs: {
        '.label': {text: label}
    }
});

graph.addCell(elem);
```

In here, the width is `length of label * (font size of label in pixel)` and the height is fixed.

But since you don't want to create a custom model, after creating the element (instance of the model), you can set the below attributes before adding it to the graph.

```
var label = "my custom label";
var elem = // create your element
elem.attributes.size.width = label.lenght*12
graph.adddCell(elem)
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I was hoping that there was a more simple and elegant way of resizing the model based on the size and length of a text label.